# window.location.href vs window.open() vs AJAX - WP8 app in Intel XDK

Tags: html, windows-phone-8, window.open, intel-xdk

I am developing an HTML5 app with **Intel SDK**, compiling for **Windows Phone 8** platform, and deploying and testing on **Nokia Lumia 530**.

I'm inside this scenario. I have to do from the same app 3 distinct action: (1) a call to the system browser passing a URL, (2) a call to the system telephone app passing a telephone number, (3) an ajax call to an API.

My problem is that window.open() doesn't works for link "tel:123456789", and if try using window.location.href for telephone action I cannot use window.open() after returning to my app after the telephone call. It seems that window.location.href inhibit/block the app context for the use of window.open().

Here's my code for clarity, I tried all combinations:

**HTML**:

```
<button class="ui-btn my-button" id="button1">Bottone 1</button>
<button class="ui-btn my-button" id="button2">Bottone 2</button>
<button class="ui-btn my-button" id="button3">Bottone 3</button>
```

**JS** [inside var onDeviceReady=function(){ }]:

```
$("#button1").on("click", function () {         
    window.open ('http://www.google.it', '_blank'); // WORKS PERFECTLY BEFORE I CLICK BUTTON 2, DOESN'T WORKS AFTER
});  

$("#button2").on("click", function () {         

    window.open ('tel:123456789', '_blank'); // WORKS BUT BLOCKS OTHERS BUTTONS ACTIONS AFTER COME BACK IN APP FROM TELEPHONE CALL
    //window.open ('tel:123456789', '_system'); // DOESN'T WORKS, BUTTON CLICK HAS NO EFFECT
    //window.open ('tel:123456789', '_self'); // DOESN'T WORKS, BUTTON CLICK HAS NO EFFECT

    //window.location.href = 'tel:123456789', '_blank'; // WORKS BUT BLOCKS OTHERS BUTTONS ACTIONS AFTER COME BACK IN APP FROM TELEPHONE CALL
    //window.location.href = 'tel:123456789', '_system'; // WORKS BUT BLOCKS OTHERS BUTTONS ACTIONS AFTER COME BACK IN APP FROM TELEPHONE CALL
    //window.location.href = 'tel:123456789', '_self'; // WORKS BUT BLOCKS OTHERS BUTTONS ACTIONS AFTER COME BACK IN APP FROM TELEPHONE CALL
}); 

$("#button3").on("click", function () { 

    // WORKS PERFECTLY BEFORE I CLICK BUTTON 2, DOESN'T WORKS AFTER
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: 'https://customers.clouditalia.com/public/ws_etnicom_ri?numerochiamato=05...',
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {                

            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("ERROR: response = " + data);
        }
    });
});
```

Someone can give me help?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use another call like:

```
$.mobile.changePage("#button1");
```

where `#button1` is the id of the page you want to go to.